# Reaching Recursion depth in python for following code

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion

I have following code to calculate the frequency of a sorted list recursively. I don't understand why there are so many recursive calls happening in this to be precise (997). What am I doing wrong over here.

```
def frequency_util(A, low, high, freq):
    if A[low] == A[high]:
        freq[A[low]] += high-low+1
    else:
        mid = (low+high)//2
        frequency_util(A, low, mid, freq)
        frequency_util(A, mid, high, freq)

def frequency(A):
    freq = [0]*A[len(A)-1]
    frequency_util(A, 0, len(A)-1, freq)

    return freq


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(frequency([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5]))
```

Comment: put bracket around mid=(low+high)//2 maybe?

Comment: Thanks did that! still getting the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an infinite recursion there.

The problem happens at several points, when you have a subproblem of size 2 with different values in each position (e.g. A[3:4] ---> [2,3]). In that case, you code is always spawning 2 additional calls to `frequency_util`, and one of them will still include the array with size 2 anyway (A[3:4] --> A[3:3], A[3:4])

You can start fixing it by adding an additional stopping condition:

```
if high - low == 1:
    freq[A[low]] += 1
    freq[A[high]] += 1
```

Also, note that there are more bugs in your code:

- You are defining a 0-indexed array to store the counts, but when updating them you are considering 1-indexing instead.
- mid should be computed like this: `mid = (low+high)//2`
- Since both low and high are counted, your second call to `frequency_util` should include only `(mid+1, high)`

Here's an example of a valid solution:

```
def frequency_util(A, low, high, freq):
    if A[low] == A[high]:
        freq[A[low]] += high-low+1
    elif high - low == 1:
        freq[A[low]] += 1
        freq[A[high]] += 1
    else:
        mid = (low+high)//2
        frequency_util(A, low, mid, freq)
        frequency_util(A, mid+1, high, freq)

def frequency(A):
    freq = [0] * (A[len(A)-1] + 1)
    frequency_util(A, 0, len(A)-1, freq)

    return freq


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(frequency([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5]))
```

Which gives as output:

> > [0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 2]